# how to increment the elements of an array by a desired value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

```
function sum(array) {
    var accumulator = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        accumulator += array[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
}

function range (start, end) {
    let arrayNum = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        arrayNum.push(i);
    }
    return arrayNum;
};

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

How to modify range function to take an optional third argument that indicates the “step” value used when building the array. If no step is given, the elements go up by increments of one, corresponding to the old behavior. The function call range(1, 10, 2) should return [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]. Make sure it also works with negative step values so that range(5, 2, -1) produces [5, 4, 3, 2].

Comment: is it an assignment? please add what you have tried or where you would add the needed change.

Comment: This reads exactly like a school assignment. Please try to learn first before asking Stack Overflow to solve your homework. There are plenty of ways to approach this problem and I suggest you start by trying to solve it before coming here for help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should be able to loop from `start` to `end` in a `for` loop and increment by `step`.

```
for(let i = start; i <= end; i+=step) { /* etc. */}
```

This doesn't work, however when `step` is negative because the condition is met immediately when `end` is less that `start`.

So you need to test whether you are going up or down before deciding what that test condition should look like.

So your range could do something like:

```js
function range (start, end, step) {
    if (!step) step = 1 // step size of zero makes no sense
    let arrayNum = [];
    // using ternary to decide stopping condition
    for (let i = start; step > 0 ? i <= end: i >= end; i += step ) {
      arrayNum.push(i);
    }
    return arrayNum;
  };
  
 console.log(range(22, 34, 5))
 console.log(range(10, -10, -2))
 console.log(range(-5, -10, -1))
```

You should also test that the arguments make sense. For example `range(10, 20, -2)` doesn't make sense and should probably throw an error. I leave that to you…

Answer (score 0):

To add in the step, just add the step to `i` in the `for` loop. In the `for` loop, you need `i` to start at `start` and end at `end`:

```
for(let i = start; i < end; i+=step){..}
```

You will need to check if the step is less than `0` to change the `for` loop to use `i >= end` instead of `i <= end`.

```js
function sum(array) {
var accumulator = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    accumulator += array[i];
return accumulator;
}

function range (start, end, step) {
  let arrayNum = [];
  step = step||1;
  var numOfTimes;
  if(step<0){
  numOfTimes = -10;
  for (let i = start; i >= end; i+=step ) {
    arrayNum.push(i);
  }
  } else {
  numOfTimes = 10;
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i+=step ) {
    arrayNum.push(i);
  }
  }
return arrayNum;
};
console.log((range(1, -10, -1)));
console.log((range(1, 10, 2)));
console.log(sum(range(1, 10, 2)));
```

Comment: How do you find this works on the example in the question: `range(5, 2, -1)`?

Comment: I’m reading eloquent JavaScript and this question is one of the exercises that I’m struggling to understand.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks for reminding me. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wish to modify the original code you provided, this is one of the many ways.

This code allows you to have the third parameter as optional.

**Note:** I am aware that this code is inefficient and can be written better. Its purpose is to give ideas on how to do it.

```js
function sum(array) {
var accumulator = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    accumulator += array[i];
return accumulator;
}

function range (start, end) {
  let doReverse = false;
  
  let steps = (arguments.length > 2) ? +arguments[2] : 1;   
  if (steps < 0){
   let temp = start;
    start = end;
    end = temp;
    steps = -steps;
    doReverse = true;
  }
  
  let arrayNum = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i = i + steps ) {
    arrayNum.push(i);
  }
  if (doReverse){
   arrayNum = arrayNum.reverse();
  }
  return arrayNum;
};

console.log(sum(range(1, 10, 2)));
console.log(range(5, 2, -1))
```